# Put an icon for the GCM push notification instead of the default one

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I know hot to set the Title,Message and Sound, 
But i have to replace the default icon while sending the push notification from server.
How can i do this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
// call your local image location 
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon);


// if you want to set image from url then use it 
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon).setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromURL("image url"));

public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not building a local notification
Its a GCM push notification, attributes must be identified on the server

Comment: U still didn't git it this is the code for local notification, my question is about push notification, it is server side implementation its not even written java

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you(Haidr) want . You asked to replace the default icon while sending the push notification from server . my code will be execute for both case , if u change it locally or send any image url using json object for push notification . just parse it and pass url . u will see the output .

Comment: What am talking about is in here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options although they mention how to set icon but it is not clear

Comment: very simple @haider , just put an image url in your json . you already told that you didn't faced any problem for showing title and message . Same way just parse image url from json and follow my post .

Answer (score 0):

As is written [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.NotificationMessagePayload#icon):

> *icon* 
>   string
>
> The notification's icon.
>
> Android: Sets the notification icon to myicon for drawable resource
>   myicon. If you don't send this key in the request, FCM displays the
>   launcher icon specified in your app manifest.
>
> Web: **The URL to use for the notification's icon.**
>
> Platforms: Android, Web

So just provide within *icon* field the URL to another icon image file that you want to use.